# comparison slider img text disapear then slide on or behind text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have img comparison slider, its working fine, but i wanna add Before and after text. Then i add it looks like not good, then you make only one img.
My img comparison slider.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GI7TREPS8JY8

```css
img-comparison-slider {
  --divider: 7x solid #c0c0c0;
  --hint-opacity: 0.8
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/img-comparison-slider@latest/dist/component/component.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule="" src="https://unpkg.com/img-comparison-slider@latest/dist/component/component.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/img-comparison-slider@latest/dist/collection/styles/initial.css" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-left">After</div>
  <div class="top-right">Before</div>
  <img-comparison-slider>
    <img slot="before" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-NNiz4A9phrs/TsOAo1JWUaI/AAAAAAAAAK8/fbU77sVAKgQ/s1600/100_4642.JPG">

    <img slot="after" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-sx7j1tzOHg0/TsN-hW9Tk2I/AAAAAAAAAEs/mlwMFHu5PkM/s1600/100_4611.JPG">
  </img-comparison-slider>
</div>
```

So i want make text disappear then my slider is on or behind text.